# Checking postgres database existense using django - throws OS error .

Tags: python, django, postgresql, supervisord

I have a django application running in a virtual environment using supervisor . Supervisor is run by `root` and application is run by user `ubuntu` .

I want to check whether a database exist in postgres or not. My function below works well in normal python shell (Repl) and even when I run my application using `python migrate.py runserver` and even in django shell .

However as soon as I start the application using supervisor and that code block executes , I get the following exception -

`Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Here's the function which is

```
def database_exists(database_name):
    try:
         db= "anydbname"
         c1 = "psql -U postgres -lqt"
         c2 = "cut -d | -f 1"
         c3 = "grep -w " + db              

         ps1 = subprocess.Popen(c1.split(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
         ps2 = subprocess.Popen(c2.split(),stdin=ps1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
         ps3 = subprocess.Popen(c3.split(),stdin=ps2.stdout , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
         result = ps3.communicate()[0]  # if empty , db not found 
         result = result.strip()
         if result == "" :
             return False
         else :
             return True 
    except Exception, e:
        raise e
        return False, str(e)
```

I failed to understand what is the exact directory or file it wants to find.Is it any kind of permission issue ? But even the normal shells are run using `ubuntu` user so doesn't seem to be permission error . How to debug it which file not found when run in supervisor ? I added the logs in supervisor but it only shows `<request url > HTTP/1.0" 500` so no clues about it .

Here's the supervisor config

```
[program:myprog]
environment=PATH="/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin"
command=python /var/www/myapp/manage.py rungevent 127.0.0.1:8010 250
directory=/var/www/myapp
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/myapp.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/myapp-err.log
```

Comment: This could be a case where its not able to find `psql` command. Try giving complete path where  `psql` is present.

Comment: hey redoc ! you nailed it man . Exactly this was the reason. This code was a part of a big system . we did few parts using pyscopg2 as suggested by @Sergey below however you saved it man.

Comment: I got the reason of it . We reassigned the PATH variable of system while in supervisor so its not able to find path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with supervisor config . It was trying to find `psql` and not getting path of it . Reason was the wrong path variable in supervisor conf . Here's the correct setting which worked well .

Change : Removed `PATH` and specified the full executable path of virtual env's python .

```
[program:myprog]
command=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/python /var/www/myapp/manage.py rungevent 127.0.0.1:8010 250
directory=/var/www/myapp
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/myapp.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/myapp-err.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need so sophisticated way to test database existence. Try this:

```
import psycopg2

def database_exists(database_name):
    con = None
    res = None
    try:
        con = psycopg2.connect(database="test", user="test", password="abcd", host="127.0.0.1") #It's better to get the parameters from settings
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT exists(SELECT 1 from pg_catalog.pg_database where datname = %s)", (database_name,))
        res = cur.fetchone()[0]
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        res = False
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . This seems to be a better way to do query rather the psql . 100% agreed . Thanks a lot .

Comment: I upvoted the answer however couldn't accept it as the solution to my problem was with supervisor config

Comment: Regarding the supervisor, try to use absolute paths to executables - psql, cut and grep.